# Add custom HTML to custom field

Tags: 7, hooks, entities, theming

In a module, I have defined a custom field. Using hook_field_formatter_info() and hook_field_formatter_view(), I can manage the display of every item (value) within that field. I want to allow the use of multiple values of this field.

***How can I add extra HTML to this 'collection'? Programmatically, from within my module.***

For example, let's say my module adds a 'fruit' field, that allows me to enter its name and its color. Now, I'd like to display this as such:

```
Name: Strawberry. Color: Red
Name: Orange. Color: Orange
Name: Lime. Color: Green
<some>Extra Html</some>
```

How to add that extra last line?

I can find references to hooks that should do it, but I simply don't understand how to tie all these pieces of information together.  I suspect I have to work with:

hook_field_prepare_view https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_prepare_view/7

I also found this resource suggesting these hooks: http://www.failover.co/blog/drupal-7-custom-field-formatter-hooks-overview

and that I should manipulate the render array.

And I tried just adding an extra element to the array, an extra delta:

```
$element[] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => "Test HTML"
);
```

But is seems to get ignored by Drupal

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but why do you not just add it in your implementation of `hook_field_formatter_view()`? You have access to the full render array containing all the field deltas, so it would seem like the most logical place to do so

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding an extra delta, as if there was an extra field value, but it get's ignored by Drupal. (edited my question to reflect this comment)

Comment: That's strange - how about adding a string based array key? e.g. `$element['footer']['#markup'] = 'foo';`

Comment: Thanks, again,... but I don't understand your comment. Do you mean altering the $page render array? Or adding 'footer' as a key instead of []    ?

Comment: Yeah adding 'footer' as the key is what I meant; you're just dealing with a standard render array there (or at least I always thought that was the case, maybe not), so in theory you should be able to add whatever you like to it, it's all going through `drupal_render()` at the end of the day. There are probably half a dozen places you could physically make this change (field template/preprocess, page hooks, entity view hooks) but it seems illogical that you'd have to resort to that when you're already building the field render array yourself from scratch!

Comment: Doesn't help much either. Could I be suffering from:
https://api.drupal.org/comment/17229#comment-17229

Comment: Yes I think you must be, I didn't know field render arrays were treated differently to normal render arrays. Seems like that's a bug, they shouldn't be IMO, but maybe they had a good reason to do it at the time. Did you try the hook_field_prepare_view() method mentioned over there? That looks promising

Comment: Thanks, @Clive - I managed to figure it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all I needed to do was to use hook_field_prepare_view() to add an extra, empty elements to the $items array

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_prepare_view().
 */
function threejs_field_prepare_view($entity_type, $entities, $field, $instances, $langcode, &$items)
{
    $items[1]['footer'] = array( );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Ideogram but here is my full code. For example I have 4 images. My formatter makes the first image the main image and the rest including the 1st image thumbnails. I need to add the extra $item to the beginning.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_prepare_view().
 */
function yourmodule_field_formatter_prepare_view($entity_type, $entities, $field, $instances, $langcode, &$items, $displays) {
  foreach ($displays as $key => $display) {
    if ($display['type'] == 'my_formatter') {
      // We need to add an extra item for the main image.
      if (isset($items[$key][0])) {
        array_unshift($items[$key], $items[$key][0]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```